# touch.facebook.com in android webview get error "Entity 'nbsp' not defined"

Tags: android, xml, facebook, webview

All I want is just display a facebook profile (wall,posts...) in my webview (which is inside a fragment).

It works well with the url "https://m.facebook.com/profile.php?_user=USER_ID" but in a hideous way because facebook mobile website is shitty.

So, i'm trying with "https://touch.facebook.com/" which works very well in my chrome browser on my phone but using it in the android webView component just display this error :

> error on line 5 a column 9645: Entity 'nbsp' not defined

So I searched on internet, it turns out to be a XML parsing error due to the webview.

Any help please ?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am getting same error inside a webview inside fragment.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't find out the solution.